# How do I RDP simultaneously and run same scheduled task in parallel in 2 different sessions?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, administration, qtp, system-administration

I have created a scheduled task with my userid and would like to run the same task in multiple sessions. What I would like to do is, I will do multiple RDP to the server where I have created the task, and run multiple instances of the task.

I can run the task perfectly, but, the problem I am facing is, the GUI that is opened through the task always opens in the first RDP session (screen).

The task opens QTP and runs a test. As there can be only one QTP that can run in a single session, I need to run multiple instances in multiple sessions.

As I am having problem with QTP RPC while trying to open from a .Net web application, I solved the problem by creating scheduled tasks through the web application, that in turn opens QTP and runs the test.

Now I am stuck, because although I can run QTP, I cannot run multiple instances.

Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to run the scheduled task on your own local workstation, or on the remote session? If remote, why don't you just duplicate the scheduled task on each remote machine.

Comment: There is only one remote machine, but multiple sessions with the same user id. We need multiple sessions because more than one QTP instances cannot run in parallel on a single session. Duplicating the schedule is not a problem, the problem is that whichever scheduled task I run from subsequent sessions (same user id), the task always fires up on the very first session.

Comment: You say "As there can be only one QTP that can run in a single session, I need to run multiple instances in multiple sessions", and on the other hand "Now I am stuck, because although I can run QTP, I cannot run multiple instances.". So what does work, and what not?

Answer (score 2):

Run the task as a different user.  Multiple tasks need multiple users.  Works on 2003.  I'm trying to get it to work on 2000 server.